# Insert rows in matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I used to have a very simple matrix. This matrix is like:

```
year    week    amount    
2002    1       687
until
2013    52      8546
```

However, some weeks were not recorded. Therefore, the following macro was written for me. This macro insert a new row, name the right year in the first column, name the right week in the second column and ad a zero in the third column.

```
Sub CreateUnrecordedWeeks()

'   Defining used objects
Dim FY  As Integer, LY  As Integer
Dim I As Integer, ii As Integer
Dim ObjDic1   As Object
Set ObjDic1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ObjDic2  As Object
Set ObjDic2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim WkRg As Range
Dim F  As Range
Set WkRg = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion


With ObjDic1
    For Each F In WkRg.Columns(1).Cells
        .Item(F.Value & "/" & F.Offset(0, 1).Value) = F.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Next F

'        AAA = .keys: BBB = .items

        FY = Evaluate("MIN((A:A))")
        LY = Evaluate("MAX(A:A)")

    For I = FY To LY
        For ii = 1 To 52
            If (.exists((I & "/" & ii))) Then
                ObjDic2.Item(I & "/" & ii) = Array(I, ii, .Item(I & "/" & ii))
            Else
                ObjDic2.Item(I & "/" & ii) = Array(I, ii, "0")
            End If
        Next ii
    Next I
End With

With ObjDic2
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Count, 3) = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.items))
End With


End Sub
```

However, my matrix changed to:

```
Year    Week    10230001   10230003 etc etc
2002    1       564        56
until
2013    52      85         5868
```

So my question is: **how should I change the macro to employ larger matrixes (174 colums at least)**

As I employ the old macro, I see that the macro actually do not insert a row, but copy the cell under it downwards. As a result, the additional columns do not move, so the wrong time variable is connected to it.  So I need to copy the whole matrix downwards or insert a row. But how?

Comment: What is your definition of "Week 1"?  The seven days starting 1 January?  The week starting with the first Monday of the year?  The week containing the first Thursday of the year?  The third of these is the ISO definition but the first two are also popular.  The definition determines which years have a week 53 so must be known before considering what missing weeks to add.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, thanks for your command. Indeed as the focus is really on the time, the week 53 should be known where to add. However, the dataset which I use has a strong seasonality. In the original dataset there is no week 53. To avoid complex statistics and see that there is no need for a week 53, I decided to see it not so much as a date en dust add it to 52

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**  Sorry the answer is in two parts.  I cannot post images using Stack Overflow's new system and the text tables I have used instead cause this answer to exceed the 30,000 character limit.  I have reported the bug and Stack Overflow's technical staff are investigating.

I have made no attempt to debug your existing code because:

- It contains simple mistakes that a very junior programmer would not make suggesting very poor quality code.  Debugging poor quality code can be from very difficult to impossible because you are not sure what the author intended.
- The problem does not justify the use of one dictionary let alone two.
- It does not do anything close to what you want so a rewrite would be necessary.

I have created some data to represent yours:

```
  |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
1 |Year   |Week   |Amounts|-->    |       |       |       |
2 |   2002|      2|     11|     21|     31|     41|     51|
3 |   2002|     15|     24|     34|     44|     54|     64|
4 |   2002|     17|       |     36|     46|     56|     66|
5 |   2002|     18|     27|     37|     47|     57|       |
6 |   2002|     43|     27|     37|     47|     57|     67|
7 |   2002|     44|     28|     38|     48|     58|     68|
8 |   2003|     21|     32|     42|     52|       |       |
9 |   2003|     23|     34|     44|     54|     64|     74|
10|   2003|     24|     10|     20|     30|     40|     50|
11|   2003|     44|     30|     40|     50|     60|     70|
12|   2003|     45|     31|     41|       |       |       |
13|   2003|     46|     32|     42|     52|     62|     72|
14|   2003|     52|     13|     23|     33|     43|     53|
15|   2003|     53|     14|     24|     34|     44|     54|
16|   2005|      1|     17|     27|     37|     47|       |
17|   2005|     29|     20|     30|     40|     50|     60|
18|   2005|     53|     19|     29|     39|     49|     59|
19|   2006|      1|     20|     30|     40|     50|     60|
20|   2006|      2|     11|     21|     31|     41|     51|
21|   2007|     53|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|
```

Points to note:

- I have omitted most of the rows so you can see all my data.  The macro below inserts all the missing rows
- You say you want the macro to handle 174 columns least.  I have added a few extra columns to demonstrate the macro can handle more than 3 columns.  I have not tested it with all columns used but it should be able to handle any number of columns up to the Excel maximum for the version you are using.
- Some of the rows have trailing empty columns.  I do not know if your data has trailing empty columns but this demonstrates that the macro is not affected by empty columns.  New rows are sized for the longest existing row.
- If there are existing rows for week 53, the macro accepts them but it only creates rows for weeks 1 to 52.
- There is no week 1 for 2002 or 2003.  I doubt week 1 is missing for any of your data but, if it is, the macro will insert it.
- There is no year 2004.  The macro adds weeks 1 to 52 for this missing year.
- The table is supposed to indicate that I have incomplete data for years 2002 to 2006.  Currently I have no data for 2007 so I have added an empty row for week 53.  The macro will insert weeks 1 to 52.  If I had not wanted a week 53, I could have made the row for week 1 and the macro would have added rows for weeks 2 to 52.  Currently you have data for 2002 to 2013.  If you wanted to start collecting data for 2014, add a single row for 2014 and the macro will add the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 2**

Start of data after macro has run.

```
   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |   I   |
1  |Year   |Week   |Amounts|-->    |       |       |       |       |       |
2  |   2002|      1|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
3  |   2002|      2|     10|     20|     30|     40|       |       |       |
4  |   2002|      3|     11|     21|     31|     41|     51|       |       |
5  |   2002|      4|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
6  |   2002|      5|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
7  |   2002|      6|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
8  |   2002|      7|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
9  |   2002|      8|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
10 |   2002|      9|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
11 |   2002|     10|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
12 |   2002|     11|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
13 |   2002|     12|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
14 |   2002|     13|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
15 |   2002|     14|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
16 |   2002|     15|     24|     34|     44|     54|     64|       |       |
17 |   2002|     16|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
18 |   2002|     17|       |     36|     46|     56|     66|       |       |
19 |   2002|     18|     27|     37|     47|     57|       |       |       |
20 |   2002|     19|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
21 |   2002|     20|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
22 |   2002|     21|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
23 |   2002|     22|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
24 |   2002|     23|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
25 |   2002|     24|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
26 |   2002|     25|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
27 |   2002|     26|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
28 |   2002|     27|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
29 |   2002|     28|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
30 |   2002|     29|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|       |       |
```

Try the macro and study my code.  I have explained the objective of each part of the macro but I have not explained most of the VBA statements since it is normally easy to look up statements once you know they exist.  For example, try searching for "Excel VBA Option Explicit".  Come back with questions but, the more you can work out for yourself, the faster you will develop.

```
Option Explicit
  ' Constants allow you to use names instead of literals that might change over
  ' time. You only have one header row and perhaps this will not change but
  ' it is better to avoid making such assumptions. If you ever do add a second
  ' header row, one change here will fix the macro.
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 2

  ' Columns can be letters or numbers with "A"=1, "B"=2, "C"=3 and so on
  Const ColYear As Long = 1
  Const ColWeek As Long = 2
  Const ColDataFirst As Long = 3

  ' Change to your name for the worksheet containing the matrix
  Const WshtName As String = "Data"
Sub CreateUnrecordedWeeks()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long
  Dim RowValues() As Variant
  Dim WeekCrnt As Long
  Dim YearCrnt As Long

  ' This stops the screen being repainted everytime a row is inserted
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' "Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion" requires/assumes that the user has started the
  ' macro with the correct worksheet active.  This may be very likely in this
  ' case but it is is a bad habit to make this assumption so best not to start.
  ' Use a With statement to specify the worksheet unless there is an
  ' operational reason why using the worksheet selected by the user is
  ' appropriate.
  With Worksheets(WshtName)

    ' Excel VBA often provides several methods of achiving the same objective.
    ' There are several methods of finding the last row and or column none of
    ' which gives what the naive programmer might expect in every situation.
    ' Separate Finds for the last row and last column containing any value is
    ' the most reliable and I believe appropriate for your situation.  In
    ' particular it allows some existing rows to have missing trailing values
    ' without this causing problrms for the macro.
    RowLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    ' "Debug.Print" outputs values to the Immediate Window (at the bottom of the screen).
    ' I use Debug.Print to check values are as I expect before moving on to the next
    ' section of the macro.
    'Debug.Print "RowLast " & RowLast
    'Debug.Print "ColLast " & ColLast

    ' Validate existing rows have valid years and weeks in ascending order
    '=====================================================================
    ' To add missing rows, the macro requires that, in every case, Row(N+1) is
    ' for a later year or week than Row(N). Validating that this requirement is
    ' met before starting the update avoiding creating a half updated matrix.

    ' For rows RowDataFirst to RowLast:
    '   1) column A must hold a value in the range 2000 to 2099
    '   2) column B must hold a value in the range 1 to 53
    '   3) Cells(Row+1,"A") must be equal to or greater than Cells(Row,"A")
    '   4) If Cells(Row+1,"A") equals Cells(Row,"A") then Cells(Row+1,"B")
    '      must be greater than Cells(Row,"B")

    ' Check the first data row here.  Within loop check the second of each
    ' pair.  This means each row is only checked once
    If Not HasRowValidYearWeek(RowDataFirst) Then
      ' User has already been told of problem
      ' "Debug.Assert False" stops execution.  I place it at the top of every path
      ' through my code.  Once it has been reached, I comment it out.  Any that remain
      ' when I have finished testing imply my testing has been inadequate.
      'Debug.Assert False
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check each data row (except the first) against the previous row
    For RowCrnt = RowDataFirst + 1 To RowLast

      If Not HasRowValidYearWeek(RowCrnt) Then
        ' User has already been told of problem
        'Debug.Assert False
        Exit Sub
      End If

      If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear) = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, ColYear) Then
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek) > .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, ColWeek) Then
          ' Same year, increased week so current row belongs after previous row
          'Debug.Assert False
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek) = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, ColWeek) Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Row " & RowCrnt & " has the same year" & _
                      " and week as the previous row.", vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        Else
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Row " & RowCrnt & _
                      " belongs before the previous row.", vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        End If
      ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear) > .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, ColYear) Then
        ' Increased year so current row belongs after previous row
        'Debug.Assert False
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False
        Call MsgBox("Row " & RowCrnt & _
                    " belongs before the previous row.", vbOKOnly)

      End If
    Next

    'Debug.Print "Data OK"

    ' Generate a row of zeros for any row to be inserted. This row is the length
    ' of the longest existing row.
    ReDim RowValues(1 To 1, 1 To ColLast)
    ' VBA allows a range to loaded to an array or an array to be loaded to a
    ' range with:
    '   1) VariantArray = Range.Value
    '   2) Range.Value = VariantArray
    ' With format 1, the interpreted ReDims VariantArray to match the range
    ' size. With format 2, The range and array sizes should match. I leave you
    ' to experiment to discover what happens if the the sizes do not match.
    ' VariantArray is a two dimensional array. The first dimension is for rows
    ' and the second for columns. The is the opposite of the normal convention
    ' but means the access matches Cells(Row, Column)
    ' RowValues(1, ColYear) and RowValues(1, ColWeek) will be overwritten when
    ' a row is inserted.
    For ColCrnt = 1 To ColLast
      RowValues(1, ColCrnt) = 0
    Next

    RowCrnt = 2

    ' The first row must be for week 1 of a year
    YearCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear).Value
    WeekCrnt = 0

    ' This is the main loop.  It cannot be a For-Loop because rows will be
    ' inserted and the end value for a For-Loop can be changed within the loop.
    ' Each repeat of this loop does one of the following:
    '  1) Determines that the next required row is already present and
    '     advances to the next row
    '  2) Determines a mid-year is missing and inserts it.  The previous
    '     current row remains the current row
    '  3) Determines the current year is complete and prepares for the next
    '  4) Determines a trailing week for a year is missing and adds it.  The
    '     year previous current row remains the current row
    Do While RowCrnt <= RowLast
      If YearCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear).Value Then
        ' Have another row for the same year
        'Debug.Assert False
        WeekCrnt = WeekCrnt + 1
        If WeekCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek).Value Then
          ' The next row is already present
          'Debug.Assert False
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1 ' Advance to next row
          ' No more processing for this loop
        Else
          ' The next row is not present
          'Debug.Assert False
          .Rows(RowCrnt).Insert  ' Insert row above RowCrnt
          RowLast = RowLast + 1
          RowValues(1, ColYear) = YearCrnt
          RowValues(1, ColWeek) = WeekCrnt
          .Range(.Cells(RowCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowCrnt, ColLast)).Value = RowValues
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1 ' Advance to previous current row
          ' No more processing for this loop
        End If
      Else
        ' Next row is for a different year
        'Debug.Assert False
        If WeekCrnt = 52 Or WeekCrnt = 53 Then
          ' YearCrnt is finished
          'Debug.Assert False
          YearCrnt = YearCrnt + 1
          WeekCrnt = 0
          ' No more processing for this loop
        Else
          ' A trailing week is missing.  Add it.
          'Debug.Assert False
          WeekCrnt = WeekCrnt + 1
          .Rows(RowCrnt).Insert  ' Insert row above RowCrnt
          RowLast = RowLast + 1
          RowValues(1, ColYear) = YearCrnt
          RowValues(1, ColWeek) = WeekCrnt
          .Range(.Cells(RowCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowCrnt, ColLast)).Value = RowValues
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1 ' Advance to previous current row
          ' No more processing for this loop
        End If
      End If

    Loop

  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
Function HasRowValidYearWeek(ByVal RowCrnt As Long) As Boolean

    ' Return True if column ColYear of RowCrnt is in the range 2000-2099 and
    ' column ColWeek of RowCrnt is in the range 1-53

    HasRowValidYearWeek = True

    With Worksheets(WshtName)

      If IsNumeric(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear).Value) Then
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear).Value >= 2000 And _
           .Cells(RowCrnt, ColYear).Value <= 2099 Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column A of first data row has good value
        Else
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Cell " & ColNumToCode(ColYear) & RowCrnt & _
                      " is not in the range 2000-2099.", vbOKOnly)
          HasRowValidYearWeek = False
        End If
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False
        Call MsgBox("Cell " & ColNumToCode(ColYear) & RowCrnt & _
                    " is not numeric.", vbOKOnly)
          HasRowValidYearWeek = False
      End If

      If IsNumeric(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek).Value) Then
        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek).Value >= 1 And _
          .Cells(RowCrnt, ColWeek).Value <= 53 Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' Column A of first data row has good value
        Else
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("Cell " & ColNumToCode(ColWeek) & RowCrnt & _
                      " is not in the range 1-53.", vbOKOnly)
          HasRowValidYearWeek = False
        End If
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False
        Call MsgBox("Cell " & ColNumToCode(ColWeek) & RowCrnt & _
                    " is not numeric.", vbOKOnly)
        HasRowValidYearWeek = False
      End If

  End With

End Function
```